# Button, Prompt, and Alert

Tags: javascript, substring, alert, prompt

I have a button element in my html that looks like this:

```
<button id = "buttonOne" type = "button" onclick = "buttonOne()">
Click Me!
</button>
```

I have a function in my js file that looks like this:

```
function buttonOne() {

    var input = prompt("Please enter your first name followed by a comma and then 
    your age (ex. Mikey, 12):");

    var name = input.substring(0, indexOf(","));

    alert(name);
}
```

What I am trying to do is alert only the name retrieved from the prompt. However, my button does not seem to be activating the prompt anymore.

Comment: Correction: I do get the prompt as I fixed the period that was supposed to be a comma in the substring, but my alert does not appear

Comment: In input.substring(0. indexOf... you have a dot (.) instead of a comma

Comment: Use your developer console. I am sure there is an error in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function buttonOne() {
  var input = prompt("Please enter your first name followed by a comma and then your age (ex. Mikey, 12):");
  var name = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(","));
  if(name){
    alert(name);
  }else{
    alert('Uh huh.. please enter in correct format');
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="buttonOne" type="button"onclick="buttonOne()">
  Click Me!
</button>
```

You need to use the following to get the name.

```
var name = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(","));
```

Comment: You really should check that input.indexOf(",") is not returning -1

Answer (score 0):

First check for the comma. If not found, show an error message.

```
   var commaIdx = input.indexOf(",");
   if (commaIdx == -1) {
     alert("Input Invalid");
   } else {
     var name = input.substring(0, commaIdx);
     alert(name);
   }
```

Comment: i don't even get the alert for input invalid, however i tried running the code  on the code snippet option on this site and it works...

whats the problem on my end?

Comment: @TommySon you should get this if you don't have a comma in input

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[1] Get `input` from `prompt`

[2] Valid `input`

[3] Split by comma `Name` and `Age`

```js
function buttonOne() {
    var input = prompt("Please enter your first name followed by a comma and then your age (ex. Mikey, 12):");
    
    if (input.indexOf(",") == -1) {
        alert("Input Invalid");
    } else {
     var info = input.split(',');
        alert("Name:" + info[0] + ", Age:" + info[1]);
    }
}
```

```html
<button id = "buttonOne" type = "button" onclick="buttonOne();">
Click Me!
</button>
```